# Is it possible to download$.post via FileSaver saveAs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm testing FileSaver saveAs function. Here's my code to fetch report data with post request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/rest/report/test',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({"date": "11.11.2015"}),
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        saveAs(response,"test.xlsx");
    }
});
```

That fails with error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

But I can see result console.log(response); - it shows file content. Is it possible to make my code to download file?

Comment: where is `saveAs` function?

Comment: `saveAs` doesn't seem to be a vanilla JS method. Looks like it is a part of `FileSaver` library.

Comment: Sorry, for confusion, saveAs is a part of FileSaver library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`saveAs` tries to execute `createObjectURL` on your text, and fails.

The reason is that `saveAs` does not accept plain text as argument. It only accepts [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) objects.

### Text files

If your server returns text, you can create `Blob` from your text by using `new Blob()` constructor.
Here is the working example:

```js
document.getElementById('download').onclick = function() {
    var text = "Hello world!";

    var blob = new Blob([text], {
        type: "text/plain; encoding=UTF-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "result.txt");
};
```

```html
<script src="http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="download">Download</a>
```

### Binary files

As long as you have binary file, you can use native `XMLHttpRequest` and use `responseType = blob`.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/rest/report/test/', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var blob = this.response;
    saveAs(blob, 'download.xlsx');
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for remark about excel. The file was downloaded but looks damaged, so I can't open it. How to download binary files? The response headers are:
Connection: keep-alive
Server: WildFly/8 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream 
Content-Length: 8740 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xlsx"

Comment: @Aeteros Try to open this link (/rest/report/test/) manually in browser - then, save this file and rename to `.xlsx`. Will it open?

Comment: It won't beacause method uses POST

Comment: @Aeteros Write a simple HTML file, which will produce this POST :)

Comment: @Aeteros Please, try another approach under **Binary files** title.

Comment: The error is the same as passing text to it: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: After adding         dataType: 'binary',
        processData: false,
        responseType: 'blob', theres no error, but file is not saved

Comment: @Aeteros I have no more ideas except for the last one. If it doesn't help, then I give up. Check my update.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late for an answer but useful for other programmer

jQuery doesn't allow to download binary files, this is what is needed here. Your call without the datatype probably default to text. Creating a blob from a text string can cause artefact to corrupt the file as the binary data was initially interpret as text.

As proposed by Yeldar answer, you call you own XMLHttpRequest but this don’t allow you to keep your code clean. jQuery allows to create Ajax transports plugins so you will be able to get a binary array contain in a blob and bypassing your costly conversion by directly calling saveAs on your response.

http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/

Github code: https://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/tree/master/BinaryTransport

Comment: A discussion on jQuery for binary transport: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1525

And another implementation that I didn’t try: https://github.com/acigna/jquery-ajax-native